Good literature for bayesian structural time series
I am currently writing on something about time series analysis, including a chapter about bayesian structural time series. I come from a math background, and understand fundamentals of time series analysis, including ARMA models etc.
Can you recommend any literature (math-theory focused) on bayesian structural time series? I am more interested about the mathematical theory than about implementations. I found it hard to find something good on the internet.

Hello. Have you taken a look at the original articles were the model is proposed? (Scott, Varian 2013, 2014)

Yeah, I checked that. Was a bit too fast for me.

West, Mike, and Jeff Harrison. Bayesian Forecasting and Dynamic Models. Springer Science & Business Media, 2006.
